# Angular Reloading Page on Href Occassionally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange error going on in my app. I use ui.router for my routes like any normal angular app. I have some buttons here and there that link to other portions of the app:

```
<a href="Modules/test/main.asp#/info">
```

Most of the time this works great, it changes routes and is fine. Sometimes though, it does a full page reload. The only portion that works every time is I have an ng-click that hits a function before change location, I shouldn't have to change routes via the controller each time if I don't want to reload though.

Comment: What about `<a href="#/info">` ?

Comment: Doing that takes me to the root of my application. i.e. localhost#/info.

Comment: Do you use `<base href="Modules/test/main.asp">` tag in your `<head>`?

Comment: What about adding `ng-click` or [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) and let controller logic do the proper action?

Comment: No I don't use base href because it's an Angular app inside of a larger application. The <head> tag is in a header file for the whole application. maremp, I can use ng-click that just doesn't seem ideal. Is that how most apps are structured?

Comment: Sorry I sent my message to fast, please read it again (I edited it).

Comment: Why not use ui-sref='{name of info state}' ?

Comment: Zack, `ui-sref` won't work because that href points to another angular app.

Comment: ui-sref actually was the way to go, I forgot that was even an option it's been so long since I worked on this app. Thanks!